# fill fragment edttexts with data from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

thx in advance to your time. This are driving me crazy, I want to fill some edit texts located into the layout of a fragment with is called by a button in the main activity and I want to have some edit text filled by data of asynctask on the main activity.I've tried with this code but when i open the fragment i can't close the fragment and is empty. please please give a solution or directions to find solution.

this is my code of the activity:

```
public class resultadoscopia extends Activity implements datos.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

ImageView foto;
Button Sig;
Button Ant;
Button Adopta;

String hld;
String postal;
String animal;


String email;
String telf;
String edad;
String nomanimal;
String funciones;
String cchld;
String neces;
String ccanimal;
String ccpostal;
String nomcont;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
public String url_product_detials = "http://adoptia.esy.es/androptar.php";

// JSON Node names
public static final String TAG_HLD = "hld";
public static final String TAG_POSTAL = "postal";
public static final String TAG_ANIMAL = "animal";
public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
public static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
public static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String TAG_TEL = "telf";
public static final String TAG_EDAD = "edad";
public static final String TAG_NANIMAL = "nomanimal";
public static final String TAG_NCONT = "nomcont";
public static final String TAG_NECES = "neces";
public static final String TAG_FUNCIONES = "funciones";
public static final String TAG_FOTO = "foto";
public Bitmap loadedImage;

int bCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultados1);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    Adopta = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_fragment);
    Adopta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Paso 1: Obtener la instancia del administrador de fragmentos
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            //Paso 2: Crear una nueva transacción
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            //Paso 3: Crear un nuevo fragmento y añadirlo

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String accanimal=ccanimal;
            String aedad=edad;
            String aemail=email;
            String acchld=cchld;
            String anomanimal=nomanimal;
            String anomcont=nomcont;
            String afunciones=funciones;
            String aneces=neces;
            String accpostal=ccpostal;
            String atelf=telf;
            bundle.putString("ccanimal",accanimal);
            bundle.putString("edad",aedad);
            bundle.putString("email",aemail);
            bundle.putString("cchld",acchld);
            bundle.putString("nomanimal",anomanimal);
            bundle.putString("nomcont",anomcont);
            bundle.putString("funciones",afunciones);
            bundle.putString("neces",aneces);
            bundle.putString("ccpostal",accpostal);
            bundle.putString("telf",atelf);
            datos fragInfo = new datos();
            fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
            transaction.add(R.id.contenedor, fragInfo);
            transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragInfo);


            //Paso 4: Confirmar el cambio
            transaction.commit();


        }
    });


    Sig = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sig);
    Ant = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ant);



    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
     hld = extras.getString(TAG_HLD);
     postal = extras.getString(TAG_POSTAL);
     animal = extras.getString(TAG_ANIMAL);


    foto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cfoto);


   // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    Sig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            bCount++;
            new GetProductDetails().execute();

        }
    });

    Ant.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            bCount--;
            new GetProductDetails().execute();

        }
    });




}



public void irselect(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(resultadoscopia.this, select.class);
    startActivity(intent);


}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {


}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(resultadoscopia.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Buscando animales...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hld", hld));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postal", postal));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("animal", animal));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("animal", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        final JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(bCount);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        ccanimal=(product.getString(TAG_ANIMAL));
                        edad=(product.getString(TAG_EDAD));
                        email=(product.getString(TAG_EMAIL));
                        cchld=(product.getString(TAG_HLD));
                        nomanimal=(product.getString(TAG_NANIMAL));
                        nomcont=(product.getString(TAG_NCONT));
                        funciones=(product.getString(TAG_FUNCIONES));
                        neces=(product.getString(TAG_NECES));
                        ccpostal=(product.getString(TAG_POSTAL));
                        telf=(product.getString(TAG_TEL));



                        URL imageUrl;
                        try {
                            imageUrl = new URL("http","adoptia.esy.es",product.getString(TAG_FOTO));
                            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                            conn.connect();
                            loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error cargando la imagen: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        foto.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);


                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details


        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_resultados, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And this the fragment code:

```
public class datos extends Fragment {

EditText email;
EditText telf;
EditText edad;
EditText nomanimal;
EditText funciones;
EditText cchld;
EditText neces;
EditText ccanimal;
EditText ccpostal;
EditText nomcont;





private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public datos() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String rAza = bundle.getString("ccanimal");
    String hld = bundle.getString("cchld");
    String postal = bundle.getString("ccpostal");
    String emilio = bundle.getString("email");
    String tel = bundle.getString("telf");
    String edade = bundle.getString("edad");
    String nomani = bundle.getString("nomanimal");
    String nece = bundle.getString("neces");
    String func = bundle.getString("funciones");
    String nomcon = bundle.getString("nomcont");

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos, container, false);

    //Nuevos parametros para el view del fragmento
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    //Nueva Regla: EL fragmento estara debajo del boton add_fragment
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.add_fragment);
    //Margenes: top:41dp
    params.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    //Setear los parametros al view
    view.setLayoutParams(params);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    ccanimal = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.canimal);
    cchld = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.chdl);
    ccpostal=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cpostal);
    email = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cemail);
    telf = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.ctelf);
    edad = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cedad);
    nomanimal = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cnomanimal);
    nomcont = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cnomcont);
    neces =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cneces);
    funciones =(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.cfunciones);

    ccanimal.setText(rAza);
    edad.setText(edade);
    email.setText(emilio);
    cchld.setText(hld);
    nomanimal.setText(nomani);
    nomcont.setText(nomcon);
    funciones.setText(func);
    neces.setText(nece);
    ccpostal.setText(postal);
    telf.setText(tel);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos, container, false);
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```